# Masonry with Flexslider

Tags: flexslider, overlapping, masonry, imagesloaded

I'm having difficulties making flexslider work with a Masonry layout in Wordpress. 
I'm already using ImagesLoaded but it doesn't work with Flexslider because of this piece of code.

```
.flexslider .slides > li {
  display: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

I did tried changing it to this one below, but it didn't quite work the way I want to.

```
.flexslider .slides > li:nth-child (1n+2) {
  display: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

My current jQuery code is:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

var $container = $('.grid-masonry');
        $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: 'article',
                singleMode: true,
            });
        });

});


jQuery(function ($) {

    $(window).load(function() {
          $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            prevText: "", 
            nextText: "",
          });
        });

});
```

Anyone an idea how to load the flexslider first before the masonry layout, so the post items don't overlap?

Comment: No one an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

After searching for days, I finally found a solution that worked for me.

Adding the following piece of code to Flexslider did the trick:

```
start: function(){
                 var $container = $('.grid-masonry');
                $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
                $container.masonry({
                        itemSelector: 'article',                        
                    });
                }); 
            },
```

Full version:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $(window).load(function() {
          $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            prevText: "", 
            nextText: "",
            start: function(){
                 var $container = $('.grid-masonry');
                $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
                $container.masonry({
                        itemSelector: 'article',                        
                    });
                }); 
            },
          });
        });

});
```